# Android. How write text on really big image (bitmap) and save that

Tags: android, image, exception

**Hi!**

Is the following problem: I need to write a long text on a fairly large image and save it there.

***Conditions:***

1. image size over 3000 x 2000;
2. Divide the image into parts is not allowed because the text to be written on an entire image from edge to edge.
3. **Added:** I can't use the Bitmap scale or Matrix scale, as it is necessary to write text on the original image (in full size).
4. **Added:** When I show the image to the user I use Bitmap scale : `options.inSampleSize = 10;` and no problems with lack of memory

***The current problem:***

When I try to load this image in Bitmap error occurs with the limitation of the memory (VM budget).

***Questions:***

1. How to text on an big image without loading it into memory?
2. Can existing libraries for this?

***Code example:***

```
// Step 1. Open image and load to Bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName); // runtime Exception like "VM budget" !
// or
//Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.big_img_1); // as in previous runtime Exception like "VM budget" !
// or
//Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);  // as in previous runtime Exception like "VM budget" !


// Step 2. Write text
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTextSize(14);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawText("some  long  long  string  over  all  image", 100, 100, paint);

// Step 3. Save bitmap to file
OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
/*
     _________________________________________________
    |                                                |
    |                                                |
    |                                                |
    |                                                |
    |                     IMG                        |
    |                                                |
    |                                                |
    |   some  long  long  string  over  all  image   |
    |________________________________________________|
    */
```

Comment: The image has transparent parts or not?

Comment: any luck on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly use the following help to load large bitmap

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

secondly to write on image and save, you can use canvas

I do something like this in an app. Use Canvas.

I edited down a piece of my code, which actually adds a couple of other images on the background and stuff too.

Meat of code:

```
private static Bitmap getPoster(...) {
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, background_id)
    .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(res.getAssets(), FONT_PATH);
font = Typeface.create(font, Typeface.BOLD);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(font);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
paint.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);
float fontSize = getFontSize(background.getWidth(), THE_QUOTE, paint); //You'll have to define a way to find a size that fits, or just use a constant size.

paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
canvas.drawText(THE_QUOTE, (background.getWidth() - paint.measureText(THE_QUOTE)) / 2,
    background.getHeight() - FILLER_HEIGHT, paint); //You might want to do something different. In my case every image has a filler in the bottom which is 50px. 
return background;
}
```

Put your own version of that in a class and feed it the image id and anything else. It returns a bitmap for you to do whatever you want with (display it in an imageview, let the user save it and set as wallpape).

Comment: In this line `Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, background_id).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);` i receive an exception "VM budget" on the image more than 3000 x 2000

Comment: Kindly use the technique here -  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html or you could use Matrix class to reduce the size of the image

Comment: I can't use the Bitmap scale or Matrix scale, as it is necessary to write text on the original image (in full size)

Comment: i would suggest add an overlay to the image and then later merge the overlay with text to the original image in the background. 
show the user a condensed view with full image and then once user writes on the overlay, you can merge the text to your original canvas to produce a new image.

Comment: I do not need to show that any user. Image processing is in background. But the dimensions of the image are so big that I can't even load it to bitmap for processing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are looking for but it might be helpful.

*If your image is not transparent* you can reduce the amount of memory you need to load it by specifying RGB_565 for it's config like this :

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image, options);
```

Comment: Full code `BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);` And still i receive an exception "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget"